# Storing Integers in Data Segment MIPS Alignment

Tags: integer, mips, cpu-word, memory-alignment

```
    .data
x:  .space  1
y:  .space  1
z:  .space  1
q:  .space  1
empty:  .space  1
string_buffer:  .space  4000

.text
main:
li $t9, ' '
la $t8, empty
sb $t9 , 0($t8)
li $t9, 1
la $t8, string_buffer
addi $t8, $t8, 0
sw $t9 , 0($t8)
```

I'm trying to store `1` in `string_buffer[0] - string_buffer[3]`, however this code produces the following exception:

```
 store address not aligned on word boundary 0x1001000a
```

Comment: Yes `string_buffer` is not word-aligned, but you're storing a word there.

Comment: How can I ensure it is word-aligned?

Comment: You could put `.align 2` before it